# GridView returning null when I try to grab the GridView to display data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to return the table of Users and display it on a page which uses a masterpage.

My master page file called AjaxMaster.Master looks like this -

```
            <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AjaxMaster.master.cs"
                Inherits="e.AjaxMaster" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head id="AjaxHead1" runat="server">
                <title></title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Global.css" />
                <style type="text/css">
                    #backtoblog a
                    {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 7px;
                        left: 15px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                </style>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ajaxhead" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="ajaxform1" runat="server">

                <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="AjaxToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server" />
                <div>
                </div>
                <asp:LoginView ID="AjaxLoginView1" runat="server">
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <div id="companyLogo">
                            <img src="images/company_logo.png" alt="Company Logo" border="0" width="123" border="0"
                                height="40" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="header">
                            <!-- start of main -->

                            <div id="welcome">
                                <a href="Welcome.aspx">Welcome</a> <strong>
                                    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" />
                                </strong>, [
                                <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" />
                                ]
                            </div>
                            <span id='sm_holder'></span>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                            <%

                                string sPagePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                                System.IO.FileInfo oFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPagePath);
                                string sPageName = oFileInfo.Name;
                            %>

                            <div>
                                <!-- start of TabContainer -->
                                <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1">
                                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Home" ID="TabPanel1">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <span>
                                                <img src="iconimages/home001.png" alt="Home" border="0" height="10px" />&nbsp;Home</span>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <!-- Start of Home -->
                                            <% Response.WriteFile("HomeTab.aspx");  %>
                                            <!-- End of Home -->
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:TabPanel>
                                    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Dashboard" ID="TabPanel7">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <p>
                                                Dashboard</p>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <!-- Start of Dashboard -->
                                            <% Response.WriteFile("DashboardTab.aspx");  %>
                                            <!-- End of Dashboard -->
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:TabPanel>
                                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Locations">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <p>
                                                Locations</p>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <!-- Start of Locations -->
                                            <% Response.WriteFile("LocationsTab.aspx");  %>
                                            <!-- End of Locations -->
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:TabPanel>
                                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="Users">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <p>
                                                Users</p>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <!-- Start of Users -->
                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: SiteSQL %>"
                                                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM aspnet_Users"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                            <!-- End of Users -->
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:TabPanel>
                                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel4" runat="server" HeaderText="Reports">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <p>
                                                Reports</p>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <!-- Start of Reports -->
                                            <% Response.WriteFile("ReportsTab.aspx");  %>
                                            <!-- End of Reports -->
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:TabPanel>
                                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel5" runat="server" HeaderText="Alerts">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <p>
                                                Alerts</p>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>

                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:TabPanel>
                                    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel6" runat="server" HeaderText="Preferences">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <p>
                                                Preferences</p>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <!-- Start of Preferences -->
                                            <!-- start of left Panel for Preferences -->
                                            <%-- <div id="leftColumn">--%>

                                            <%--   </div>--%>
                                            <!-- end of left Panel for Preferences -->
                                            <!-- End of Preferences -->
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:TabPanel>
                                </asp:TabContainer>
                                <!-- end of TabContainer -->

                                <div class="clear">
                                </div>
                                <div class="line">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                </div>

                                <div id="footer">

                                </div>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        You are not logged in.
                        <br />
                        Please login to access eservice
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

And the code-behind file which looks like this -

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.UI;
            using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
            using System.Data.SqlClient;

            namespace e
            {
                public partial class AjaxMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
                {
                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {



                        if (!IsPostBack)
                        {
                            BindUsersGrid();
                        }
                    }


                    private void BindUsersGrid()
                    {
                        SqlConnection conn;
                        SqlCommand comm;

                        SqlDataReader reader;

                        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSQL"].ConnectionString;

                        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


                        comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM aspnet_Users", conn);

                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                            GridView gridviewusers = (GridView)AjaxLoginView1.FindControl("GridView1");



                            gridviewusers.DataSource = reader;

                            gridviewusers.DataBind();


                            reader.Close();


                        }

                        finally
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }


                    }


                }
            }
```

It compiles ok but when I run it, the line -

```
GridView gridviewusers = (GridView)AjaxLoginView1.FindControl("GridView1");
```

returns null and the following lines throw an exception -

```
            gridviewusers.DataSource = reader;

            gridviewusers.DataBind();
```

The stack trace of the exception looks like this -

```
             Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

            Source Error:

            An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

            Stack Trace:

            [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
               eservice.AjaxMaster.BindUsersGrid() in AjaxMaster.Master.cs:115
               eservice.AjaxMaster.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in AjaxMaster.Master.cs:27
               System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
               System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
               System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
               System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
               System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
               System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627


            Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3614
```

Line 115 of AjaxMaster.Master.cs is -

```
gridviewusers.DataSource = reader;
```

Comment: Where is AjaxLoginView1 in your page markup?

Comment: Line 5 after <body>. I had accidentally renamed it to MyLoginView1 but when I changed it AjaxLoginView1, I'm still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this.Master.GridView1?
I think you can try this.Master.FindControl("GridView1")

Answer (score 0):

Classic naming container problem.  GridView is not in the current context because it is contained in the tab panel.  FindControl is not recursive.

Try TabContainer1.ActiveTab.FindControl("GridView1")

Comment: It says "The name 'TabPanel3' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Probably need to use TabContainer1.ActiveTab.FindControl("GridView1")

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use FindControl.  You can refer to it as GridView1.

```
GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

will populate the GridView.

The reason that it is null is because you don't have the GridView your are referring to inside of the AjaxLoginView1.  In the code you posted here, it is a child of the MasterPage.

Comment: If I refer to it directly, it complains as follows - The name 'GridView1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: So let's say, I have another page called UsersGridView.aspx, what would be the best way to have it display the grid generated from that page in the tab for Users in the above situation?

Comment: can't refer to it by name because it is container in a tabpanel

Comment: If you put the GridView into its own UserControl, you wouldn't have to worry about traversing the control tree to get to the right container so you can populate it.

Sorry for missing the obvious TabPanel control being used.